Errors when creating a new project with Expo
These errors came up after I wrote npx create-expo-app@latest (I got from https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/create-a-project/) into my terminal.
I am newe to React Native and mobile development and I wanted to create an app using React Native, and followed the instructions on their web at https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Which then brought me to Expo's web. As of writing this, I have the latest Node.js v20.18.0 installed and Git 2.46.2 installed. This is what I wrote inside my command line and the error it gave me.
PS C:\Users\azri1> npx create-expo-app@latest
√ What is your app named? ... Welcome
√ Downloaded and extracted project files.
> npm install
npm warn deprecated osenv@0.1.5: This package is no longer supported.
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-catch-binding instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-logical-assignment-operators instead.
npm warn deprecated rimraf@2.6.3: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread instead.
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated abab@2.0.6: Use your platform's native atob() and btoa() methods instead
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-async-generator-functions instead.
npm warn deprecated glob@7.1.6: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.1.6: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.1.6: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm warn deprecated domexception@4.0.0: Use your platform's native DOMException instead
npm warn cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm warn cleanup   [
npm warn cleanup     'C:\\Users\\azri1\\Welcome\\node_modules\\@expo\\prebuild-config',
npm warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\azri1\Welcome\node_modules\@expo\prebuild-config\build\plugins\unversioned'] {
npm warn cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm warn cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\azri1\\Welcome\\node_modules\\@expo\\prebuild-config\\build\\plugins\\unversioned'
npm warn cleanup     }
npm warn cleanup   ],
npm warn cleanup   [
npm warn cleanup     'C:\\Users\\azri1\\Welcome\\node_modules\\@expo',
npm warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\azri1\Welcome\node_modules\@expo\cli\static\shims'] {
npm warn cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm warn cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\azri1\\Welcome\\node_modules\\@expo\\cli\\static\\shims'
npm warn cleanup     }
npm warn cleanup   ],
npm warn cleanup   [
npm warn cleanup     'C:\\Users\\azri1\\Welcome\\node_modules\\react-native',
npm warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\azri1\Welcome\node_modules\react-native\ReactCommon\react\renderer\components\view\platform\cxx'] {
npm warn cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm warn cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\azri1\\Welcome\\node_modules\\react-native\\ReactCommon\\react\\renderer\\components\\view\\platform\\cxx'
npm warn cleanup     }
npm warn cleanup   ],
npm warn cleanup   [
npm warn cleanup     'C:\\Users\\azri1\\Welcome\\node_modules\\@react-native',
npm warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\azri1\Welcome\node_modules\@react-native\gradle-plugin\react-native-gradle-plugin'] {
npm warn cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm warn cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\azri1\\Welcome\\node_modules\\@react-native\\gradle-plugin\\react-native-gradle-plugin'
npm warn cleanup     }
npm warn cleanup   ]
npm warn cleanup ]
npm error code 1
npm error path C:\Users\azri1\Welcome\node_modules\babel-plugin-react-compiler
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c ./scripts/link-react-compiler-runtime.sh
npm error '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm error operable program or batch file.
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\azri1\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-10-08T06_12_48_722Z-debug-0.log
Something went wrong installing JavaScript dependencies. Check your npm logs. Continuing to create the app.
Error: npm install exited with non-zero code: 1

✅ Your project is ready!

To run your project, navigate to the directory and run one of the following npm commands.

- cd Welcome
- npm run android
- npm run ios # you need to use macOS to build the iOS project - use the Expo app if you need to do iOS development without a Mac
- npm run web
PS C:\Users\azri1>

Though the errors showed up, it did say my project was ready to go.
I didn't want to start any projects yet, as I wanted to solve those errors before moving forward. I don't want to run into any errors in the future, thinking it might be linked to this error I'm facing here if I don't solve it. I have tried looking up online about these problems such as the npm error code 1 and '.' not recognized as an internal or external command, but I don't understand what they are and what it is I'm supposed to do to solve them. All the discussions I read online, like on reddit and github seem to not provide the exact solution, very vague and sometimes unique in their way that I don't understand. I appreciate it if anyone would kindly explain to me what I'm currently facing and guide me into solving my issues. I simply want to create a mobile app by following instructions on official online resources.
